# Creating a cumulative distribution within a column of a matrix in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, apply, lapply

I have a situation where there are c probability distributions. Each distribution has r possiblities. So I can model this with a (r x c) matrix where the c'th column represents the c'th probability distribution. The element at [r,c] represents the probability of getting the r'th possibility from the c'th probability distribution. I name this matrix probDist.

I want to generate a cumulative probability distribution matrix, so that each element at [r,c] in the matrix is the sum of the elements from [1,c] to [r-1,c].

I am coding in R. Currently, my code is as follows:

```
cumProbDist <- probDist
for(c in 1:ncol(probDist))
    cumProbDist[c] <- cumsum(probDist[c])
```

Which works correctly, but I am aware that the for function is strongly frowned upon in R code due to being inefficient. **How may I rewrite this chunk of code to utilize the *apply family of functions (or something similarly efficient) instead?**

Comment: Is the code above correct, or did you mean `probDist[, c]`? It would help if you provided a [reproducible example]() so that methods can be verified. Chances are `cumProbDist <-apply(probDist, 2, cumsum)` would work

Comment: I did indeed mean `probDist[, c]`. That line worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cumProbDist = apply(probDist,2,cumsum)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Seriously? Could you please tell me how my answer does not address the question? The question is even in bold. Have you read it?

Comment: Thanks for your response! The code worked for me. If I understand correctly, what the apply function is doing here is going through each column of the probDist matrix and applying the cumsum function to it. If the function was `apply(probDist, 1, cumsum)` instead, then the code would be doing the cumsum function for each row instead, correct?